# latex syntax help

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to type subscripts and superscripts with more than onw letter.
for example X with subscripts 120n  when n itself has a subscript of zero.

Thank you

Comment: This should really be asked on tex.stackexchange.com, but the answer is 120_{n_0}: $120_{n_0}$.

Comment: sorry about that. I am not an expert yet. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is a great help...

Answer (score 2):

To type superscripts and subscripts, use carets (^) and underscores (_) followed by braces {} for the contents inside.  (Of course, enclose everything in dollar signs.)

> Superscripts: typing e^{i \pi}+1=0 produces $e^{i \pi}+1=0$.
>
> Subscripts: Typing \dfrac {y_{1}-y_{0}}{x_{1}-x_{0} produces $\dfrac {y_{1}-y_{0}}{x_{1}-x_{0}}$
>
> Integrals: Typing \int_0^{\pi} \cos x \ dx produces $\int_0^{\pi} \cos x \ dx$

And...typing X_{120n_{0}} for your example produces $X_{120n_{0}}$.